# Implement a 1-bit adder.

Tags: computer-science, binary

The truth table is:

A B Sum

0 0 0

0 1 1

1 0 1

1 1 0

So no carry.  Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: So you have 4 output pins in your image. How do you use that to form a Sum output?

Comment: So if I combine them all with an or gate will that do it?

Comment: Then you have $Sum = AB+\overline AB+A\overline B+AB$. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, I guess not.

Comment: When $A = B = 1$, then $Sum$ should be $0$ from your truth table. Looks like $AB$ term should not be there.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a XOR gate, everything is simple and you can simply calculate $Sum = A\oplus B$, where $\oplus$ denotes exclusive OR.

If you wish to implement $Sum$ with AND-OR logic / sum of products, find out all those product terms that gives $1$. In this case, only $A\overline B$ and $\overline AB$ gives $1$, and doing an OR operation over these two gives your $Sum$.

You can also try to implement $Sum$ with OR-AND logic / product of sums, by finding out all those terms that gives $0$.